# How to connect to local docker daemon?

Tags: docker, minikube

I set up minikube and ran `eval $(minikube docker-env)`. Now after stopping the use of minikube I am getting `Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://192.168.99.100:2376. Is the docker daemon running?`. I no longer want to use minikube and instead I want to use my local docker daemon. How do I switch back to using localhost?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory, just exit your current shell and create a new one.  That is, either log out/log back in, or just close the terminal in which you ran `eval $(minikube docker-env)`.

Runing that `eval ...` command simply sets up the `DOCKER_HOST` environment variable in your current shell, which tell Docker to connect to something other than the local Docker socket.

Comment: Wow it was that simple. Thank you!